# ES6 Promises confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following snippet of code inside asynchronous function -

```
  await application.save((err) => {
    console.log("hello");
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: "Error encountered" });
    }
  });
  console.log("hey");
```

Why does "hey" get printed out earlier than "hello"? And how to fix it so the behaviour is as expected (asynchronous save operation is waited for and only when it's done and "hello" is printed, "hey" should be printed).

Following code does actually save object to MongoDB, but when I use `application.save().then(() => {})` I get an error "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: What does application.save's function signature look like?

Comment: if you are using await then no need to pass a callback wrap it around try and catch block

Comment: [If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#description) So, `application.save` is not returning a Promise.

Comment: in general - an asynchronous function that takes a callback doesn't return a Promise - there are some smart libraries that have a single function that takes a callback and returns nothing useful if you use it, or will return a Promise if you don't supply a callback

Comment: is where your mixing a callback with async/await, your need to resolve both or just the promise, for example https://playcode.io/797474/

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing between callbacks and promises.

For example, we have first task F, long task T and next task N. We want to ensure the code run in the order F -> T -> N. To do that, we need either callbacks or promises.

**Callbacks**

```js
function F() {}

function T(cb) {
  // do that long task here
  cb(err); // then call the cb and pass is the err
}

function N() {}

function main() {
  F();
  cb = (err) => {
    if (err) { // handle err }
    else {
      N() // N needs to be run in cb
    }
    // clean up
    // N can also be put here if you want to guarantee N will run
  };
  T(cb);
}
```

**Promises**

```js
function F() {}

function T(cb) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // do that long task here
        if(err) {
            reject();
        } else {
            resolve();
        }
    });
}

function N() {}

// using .then .catch .final
function main() {
  F();
  T().then(N())
     .catch(() => {
       // handle error
     })
     .finally(() => {
       // clean up
       // N can also be put here if you want to guarantee N will run
     })
}

// using async/await
async function main() {
  F();
  try {
    await T();
    N();
  } catch {
    // handle error
  } finally {
    // clean up
    // N can also be put here if you want to guarantee N will run
  }
}
```

In your case, `save()` function does not return a promise but expects a callback to be passed in. If you want a quick and simple solution, put your `console.log("hey");` in the callback. A better way is to ***promisify*** that callback function so it returns a promise and you can await it. Here is a sample promisify function to turn functions accepting callbacks into functions returning promises:

From

```js
function T(...args, cb) {
  // do that long task here
  cb(err, data)
}
```

To

```js
function TAsync(...args) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    T(...args, function(err, data) {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(data)
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if a function returns a promise you just need to use the await and assign the return to a variable which is the response. You shoud always use a try catch because promises can launch exceptions.

```
function divide(i, j) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if(j == 0) {
            reject("division by zero.");
        } else {
            resolve(i / j);
        }
    });
}

async function main() {
    try {
        let resp = await divide(5, 2);
        console.log(`resp = ${resp}`);
        resp = await divide(2, 0);
        console.log(`resp 2 = ${resp}`);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(`catch = ${e}`);
    }
}
// another way to use promises
divide(5,2).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
divide(5,0).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});

main();
```

probably your function isn't returning a promise.